# Getting Sensor Average using Arrays?

Tags: c++, arduino

First of all, let me be clear: I'm a total noob, I have close to zero programming experience and I know i'm out of my league, but I want to learn and understand.
Here's the issue. The following code has been made to control heat pads using 4 relays that turn off/on depending on the temperature that 4 lm35 Temp sensors pick up. Because these sensors can be jumpy sometimes, I want to get the average temperature from, let's say, 50 readings, and make the code check THAT data instead of the raw temp reading.
I have the code for the arduino (I wrote some code and guys over other forums took it and modified it to make it shorter (and that kind of lost me, but the code works)
and then I searched smoothing data and got a piece of code that does exactly what I want: make an array, calculate the average temp, and keep deleting and adding new data.

I tried to join both codes together and I got all different kind of errors, lol
So here I am.

**The Code that works without average data is this one:**

```
const byte tempPin[] = {A1, A2, A3, A4};
const byte relayPin[] = {6, 7, 8, 9};

// hysteresis = upperLimit - lowerLimit
const byte lowerLimit = 24;
const byte upperLimit = 31;

float tempC[4];
word reading[4];



word printInterval = 1000; // 1 second
unsigned long printCheck = 0, lastPrintTime = 0;

void setup()
{
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pinMode(relayPin[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(relayPin[i], OUTPUT); // defaults HIGH, relay OFF
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // readings and control
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    reading[i] = analogRead(tempPin[i]);
    tempC[i] = reading[i] / 9.31;


    if (tempC[i] < lowerLimit) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin[i], LOW);   //relay OFF
    }
    else if (tempC[i] > upperLimit) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin[i], HIGH);  // relay ON
    }
  }
  printCheck = millis() - lastPrintTime;
  if (printCheck >= printInterval) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print("tempC");
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.println(tempC[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();
    lastPrintTime = millis(); // reset print timer
  }
}
```

**The average code I got from Arduino Learning center is this one:**

```
/*

  Smoothing

  Reads repeatedly from an analog input, calculating a running average
  and printing it to the computer.  Keeps ten readings in an array and
  continually averages them.

  The circuit:
    * Analog sensor (potentiometer will do) attached to analog input 0

  Created 22 April 2007
  By David A. Mellis  <dam@mellis.org>
  modified 9 Apr 2012
  by Tom Igoe
  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Smoothing

  This example code is in the public domain.


*/


// Define the number of samples to keep track of.  The higher the number,
// the more the readings will be smoothed, but the slower the output will
// respond to the input.  Using a constant rather than a normal variable lets
// use this value to determine the size of the readings array.
const int numReadings = 10;

int readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int readIndex = 0;              // the index of the current reading
int total = 0;                  // the running total
int average = 0;                // the average

int inputPin = A0;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication with computer:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize all the readings to 0:
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) {
    readings[thisReading] = 0;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // subtract the last reading:
  total = total - readings[readIndex];
  // read from the sensor:
  readings[readIndex] = analogRead(inputPin);
  // add the reading to the total:
  total = total + readings[readIndex];
  // advance to the next position in the array:
  readIndex = readIndex + 1;

  // if we're at the end of the array...
  if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
    // ...wrap around to the beginning:
    readIndex = 0;
  }

  // calculate the average:
  average = total / numReadings;
  // send it to the computer as ASCII digits
  Serial.println(average);
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

**The monster I created joining both codes is this one:**

```
const byte tempPin[] = {A1, A2, A3, A4};
const byte relayPin[] = {6, 7, 8, 9};

// hysteresis = upperLimit - lowerLimit
const byte lowerLimit = 24;
const byte upperLimit = 31;

float tempC[4];
word reading[4];

const int numReadings = 50;
int readings[numReadings];
int readIndex = 0;
int total = 0;
float average[4];


word printInterval = 1000; // 1 second
unsigned long printCheck = 0, lastPrintTime = 0;

void setup()
{
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pinMode(relayPin[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(relayPin[i], OUTPUT); // defaults HIGH, relay OFF
  }
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++){
    readings[thisReading] = 0;
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // readings and control
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    reading[i] = analogRead(tempPin[i]);
    tempC[i] = reading[i] / 9.31;
    total[i] = total[i] - readings[readIndex];
    readings[readIndex] = tempC[i]
    total[i] = total[i] + readings[readIndex]
    readIndex[i] = readIndex[i] + 1 ;
    if (readIntex[i] >= numReadings) {
      readIndex = 0;
    }
    average[i] = total[i] / numReadings;

    if (average[i] < lowerLimit) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin[i], LOW);   //relay OFF
    }
    else if (average[i] > upperLimit) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin[i], HIGH);  // relay ON
    }
  }
  printCheck = millis() - lastPrintTime;
  if (printCheck >= printInterval) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print("tempC");
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.println(tempC[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();
    lastPrintTime = millis(); // reset print timer
  }
}
```

**These are the errors that I got:**

```
Arduino: 1.6.8 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

\temprelayfinal2.ino: In function 'void loop()':

temprelayfinal2:40: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

     total[i] = total[i] - readings[readIndex];

            ^

temprelayfinal2:40: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

     total[i] = total[i] - readings[readIndex];

                       ^

temprelayfinal2:42: error: expected ';' before 'total'

     total[i] = total[i] + readings[readIndex]

     ^

temprelayfinal2:44: error: 'readIntex' was not declared in this scope

     if (readIntex[i] >= numReadings) {

         ^

temprelayfinal2:47: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

     average[i] = total[i] / numReadings;

                         ^

exit status 1
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: What is the type of `total`?  Is it an array type?

Comment: the problem with the `total` is, that it is not an array so you cannot do `total[i]`

Comment: TLDR; Might be a good time to start unit testing small units (functions, modules, ...) of code.

Comment: @NathanOliver `total` is `int`

Comment: @KevinWallis I know that.  I am trying to get the OP to reason about the problem themselves.

Comment: It's generally a good idea when posting a question to narrow down the code to the relevant part instead of posting your entire program.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**: others have already pointed out the reasons why your code does not compile in the comments to your question.

More in detail, you **declare** neither *total* nor *readIndex* to be **arrays**, there is a **typo** (*readIntex* instead of *readIndex* at line *44*) and two **missing semi-columns** (lines *41* and *42*).

**However**, after carefully reading your code I think that even by applying those *syntactic* fixes you will not obtain a piece of code that does what you want.

Thus, I will provide here with my *interpretation* of your *desired* source code based on the description of your problem and your attempt.

I could verify that it compiles, however *-since I lack the hardware-* I could not test it.

> (**disclaimer:** I am rather *rusty* with *Arduino*'s *style guide* so
>   I apologise in advance for adopting a *personal* code styling.)

---

```
#include<Arduino.h>

#define NUM_SENSORS  4
#define NUM_READINGS 5
#define LOWER_LIMIT 24
#define UPPER_LIMIT 31
#define PRINT_PERIOD 1000
#define TEMPERATURE_FACTOR 9.31

/* global variables */

const byte tempPin[] = {A1, A2, A3, A4};
const byte relayPin[] = {6, 7, 8, 9};

word readings[NUM_SENSORS][NUM_READINGS] = {};
word totals[NUM_SENSORS] = {};
float averages[NUM_SENSORS] = {};

unsigned long time_elapsed = 0;
word num_readings = 0;
word j = 0;

/* setup */

void setup()
{
  analogReference(INTERNAL);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    pinMode(relayPin[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(relayPin[i], OUTPUT); // defaults HIGH, relay OFF
  }
}

/* main loop */

void loop()
{
  // keep track of actual readings:
  // (prevents under-estimation of initial values
  // due to a too large smoothing window)
  if (num_readings < NUM_READINGS)
  {
    num_readings++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    // subtract the last reading:
    totals[i] = totals[i] - readings[i][j];
    // read from the sensor:
    readings[i][j] = analogRead(tempPin[i]);
    // add the reading to the total:
    totals[i] = totals[i] + readings[i][j];

    // update average
    averages[i] = ((float) totals[i] / TEMPERATURE_FACTOR) / (float) num_readings;

    // uncomment to optionally delay action on relays
    // up until when the smooth window has been filled up
    // if (num_readings == NUM_READINGS) {
      if (averages[i] < LOWER_LIMIT)
      {
        digitalWrite(relayPin[i], LOW);   // relay OFF
      } else if (averages[i] > UPPER_LIMIT) {
        digitalWrite(relayPin[i], HIGH);  // relay ON
      }
    // }
  }

  // advance the reading index:
  j = (j + 1) % NUM_READINGS;

  unsigned long curr_time = millis();
  static unsigned long start_time = curr_time; // initialized only once

  if ((curr_time - start_time) >= PRINT_PERIOD)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      Serial.print("tempC");
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.println(averages[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();
    start_time = curr_time; // not really best solution, but
                            // i don't want to bloat the code
  }

  delay(1); // waste some time
}
```

**Note**: I kept *totals* and *readings* of type *word* so as to avoid the typical hindrances of *floating point* operations.

---

**Additional Notes**:

1. having a smooth window of *50* readings sounds very suspicious to me, in my experience the last 3-5 readings should suffice, perhaps with a larger *delay* in-between.
2. since you're still learning, I suggest you to share your *working* (small) projects on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ from time to time, so as to get some *very nice* feedback. (: